# Replace null values in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I saw a solution here but when I tried it doesn't work for me.

First I import a cars.csv file :

```
val df = sqlContext.read
              .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
              .option("header", "true")
              .load("/usr/local/spark/cars.csv")
```

Which looks like the following :

```
+----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+
|year| make|model|             comment|blank|
+----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+
|2012|Tesla|    S|          No comment|     |
|1997| Ford| E350|Go get one now th...|     |
|2015|Chevy| Volt|                null| null|
```

Then I do this :

```
df.na.fill("e",Seq("blank"))
```

But the null values didn't change.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The statement `df.na.fill("e",Seq("blank"))` returns a new `DataFrame` so `df` will not be modified. Are you assigning it into a new `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is basically very simple. You'll need to create a new `DataFrame`. I'm using the `DataFrame df` that you have defined earlier.

```
val newDf = df.na.fill("e",Seq("blank"))
```

`DataFrame`s are *immutable structures*. 
Each time you perform a transformation which you need to store, you'll need to affect the transformed `DataFrame` to a new value.

Comment: There is no error message. The null values comes from 0/0 divide but I cannot replace of with   `val newDf = outputDF.na.fill("0", Seq("blank"))`

Comment: @mathema do you mind asking a question describing your problem with a reproducible example ? I can't figure out what's wrong with your actual describe and I don't think that your problem can fit nicely into comments

Comment: My dataframe has also null values comes from 0/0 dividing. The type of field is a kind of string. I tried to replace null values using `val newDf = outputDF.na.fill("0", Seq("blank"))` and showing with `newDf.show()` but it don't work. Dataframe example https://i.imgur.com/qrWZXg8.png

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that I have asked @mathema

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188992/discussion-between-eliasah-and-mathema).

Comment: So, while the above solution works for me, Cant we use this approach? Well, it didnt work for me, so i thought, i must be doing something wrong on the syntax or usage. .withColumn("blank", when(col("blank") === null, 0).otherwise(col("blank"))). It doesnt take effect even after assigning to another DF variable.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve same in java this way

```
Dataset<Row> filteredData = dataset.na().fill(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column was string type,

`val newdf= df.na.fill("e",Seq("blank"))`

would work.

Since it's float type (as the image tells) you need to use

`val newdf= df.na.fill(0.0, Seq("blank"))`