# How to handle nulls in SparkSQL Dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is the code that I am following:

```
val ebayds = sc.textFile("/user/spark/xbox.csv")

case class Auction(auctionid: String, bid: Float, bidtime: Float, bidder: String, bidderrate: Int, openbid: Float, price: Float)

val ebay = ebayds.map(a=>a.split(",")).map(p=>Auction(p(0),p(1).toFloat,p(2).toFloat,p(3),p(4).toInt,p(5).toFloat,p(6).toFloat)).toDF()

ebay.select("auctionid").distinct.count
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
 For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace null values in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376571/replace-null-values-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: It looks like you have an empty String `""`, not `null`. No?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrameNaFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html)

> DataFrame fill(double value) Returns a new DataFrame that replaces
>   null values in numeric columns with value.
>
> DataFrame fill(double
>   value, scala.collection.Seq cols) (Scala-specific) Returns a
>   new DataFrame that replaces null values in specified numeric columns.

Example Usage :

```
df.na.fill(0.0,Seq("your columnname"))
```

for that column null values will be replaced with 0.0 or any default value.

`replace` is also useful for replacing empty strings with default values

> replace public  DataFrame replace(String col,
>                       java.util.Map replacement) Replaces values matching keys in replacement map with the corresponding values. Key
>   and value of replacement map must have the same type, and can only be
>   doubles or strings. If col is "*", then the replacement is applied on
>   all string columns or numeric columns.
>
> import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
>
> // Replaces all occurrences of 1.0 with 2.0 in column "height".
>   df.replace("height", ImmutableMap.of(1.0, 2.0));
>
> // Replaces all occurrences of "UNKNOWN" with "unnamed" in column
>   "name".    df.replace("name", ImmutableMap.of("UNKNOWN", "unnamed"));
>
> // Replaces all occurrences of "UNKNOWN" with "unnamed" in all
>   string columns.    df.replace("*", ImmutableMap.of("UNKNOWN",
>   "unnamed"));   Parameters: col - name of the column to apply the value
>   replacement replacement - value replacement map, as explained above
>   Returns: (undocumented) Since:
>   1.3.1

for example :

```
df.na.replace("your column", Map(""-> 0.0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It returned a dataframe. Here `A` and `B` are columns and `1.0` and `"unknown"` are values to be replaced.

```
df.na.fill(Map("A" -> "unknown","B" -> 1.0))
```