# Check null column value and replace it with a CONSTANT in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am new to Spark and Scala.

I have created a `DataFrame` from a csv in Spark.
There is a column in the generated `DataFrame` which has a null value for some rows.

I want to check for this null value and replace it with a constant word say "Hello".

How can I do this in Spark?

Here is my sample code to create a dataframe from csv.

```
val DFCsv = spark.read.format("csv") .option("sep", ',') .option("inferSchema", "true") .option("header", "true") .load("/tmp/my.csv")
 DFCsv.show()
```

Now one of the columns in that dataframe named "id" is null or empty/blank for some of the rows.

How can I iterate over each row one by one and then fill out column named "id" with a constant "Hello" String.

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace null values in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376571/replace-null-values-in-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One of the easiest way is to surround the null value with a Option and then do a pattern match on it.

```
Option(null) gets converted to None
Option(null).getOrElse("Hello)
```

Comment: Here is my sample code to create a dataframe from csv.

val DFCsv = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("sep", ',')
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load("/tmp/my.csv")

    DFCsv.show()

Now one of the columns in that dataframe named "id" is null or empty/blank for some of the rows.How can I iterate over each row one by one and then fill out column named "id" with a constant "Hello" String.